# A regex to match a comma that isn't surrounded by quotes

Tags: java, regex, clojure

I'm using Clojure, so this is in the context of Java regexes.

Here is an example string:

```
{:a "ab,cd, efg", :b "ab,def, egf,", :c "Conjecture"}
```

The important bits are the commas after each string. I'd like to be able to replace them with newline characters with Java's replaceAll method. A regex that will match *any* comma that is not surrounded by quotes will do.

If I'm not coming across well, please ask and I'll be happily to clarify anything.

*edit: sorry for the confusion in the title. I haven't been awake very long.*

String: `{:a "ab, cd efg",}` <-- In this example, the comma at the end would be matched, but the ones inside the quote would not.

String: `{:a 3, :b 3,}` <-- Every single comma matches.

String `{:a "abcd,efg" :b "abcedg,e"}` <-- Every single comma doesn't match.

Comment: can you add an example where every single comma matches, and one where every single comma doesnt match

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The regex:

```
,\s*(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

Matches:

```
{:a "ab,cd, efg", :b "ab,def, egf,", :c "Conjecture"}
                ^                  ^
                ^                  ^
```

and:

```
{:a "ab, cd efg",}
                ^
                ^
```

and does not match a comma in:

```
{:a "abcd,efg" :b "abcedg,e"}
```

But when escaped quotes can appear, like so:

```
{:a "ab,\" cd efg",} // only the last comma should match
```

then a regex solution won't work.

A brief explanation of the regex:

```
,            # match the character ','
\s*          # match a whitespace character: [ \t\n\x0B\f\r] and repeat it zero or more times
(?=          # start positive look ahead
  (          #   start capture group 1
    [^"]*    #     match any character other than '"' and repeat it zero or more times
    "        #     match the character '"'
    [^"]*    #     match any character other than '"' and repeat it zero or more times
    "        #     match the character '"'
  )*         #   end capture group 1 and repeat it zero or more times
  [^"]*      #   match any character other than '"' and repeat it zero or more times
  $          #   match the end of the input
)            # end positive look ahead
```

In other words: match any comma that has zero, or an even number of quotes ahead of it (until the end of the string).

Comment: Looks like you did the opposite of what I wanted. :p

I want to match the commas that /aren't/ in the string. :)

Comment: Ah, since you did not escape the quotes inside your string, I assumed that the first and last quote were also a part of your literal. My regex is still correct, btw. See my edit.

Comment: this helped me with my problem thank you very much