# Javascript Replace Single Quote

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string
`'ABC':"sharath\'"`

which I want to change to
`"ABC":"sharath\'"`

But whenever I want to replace outside single quote with double quote, it also replaces the inside one.

```
var data = "'ABC':\"sharath\\'\"";
var data1 = data.replace(/\'/g,'\"');
```

Do you have any resolution you can suggest for this?

Comment: `var data = 'ABC':"sharath\'"` throws *SyntaxError: Unexpected token :*. Can you provide a test case that actually shows the problem?

Comment: Is that a string or a (JSON) object?

Comment: if this is a single string it should be "'ABC':\"sharath\\'\""

Comment: Agree with @putvande, your string isn't really a string.

Comment: var data = {'ABC':"sharath\'"} makes sense, but what you wrote doesn't. Check it again

Comment: If you literally want the string `'ABC':"sharath\'"`, you will need to define it like `var data = "'ABC':\"sharath\\'\""`? Currently your first line throws a syntax error because you're mismatching the quotes.

Comment: i know, what i have written doesnt make any sense, and yes it's json object, i just dint enclosed it with {}. for now take it as string and use window.prompt to input that String.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, but it will not work with multiple escape characters

```
var data = "'ABC':\"sharath\\'\"";
data.replace(/([^\\]|^)\'/g,'$1\"')
```

Comment: It just added this as a comment when you put as answer +1

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this helps you, because it's kind of dirty but:

```
strSplitted = "'ABC':'sharath'".split(":");
newStr = strSplitted[0].replace(/(\')/g, "\"") + ":" + strSplitted[1];
```

Comment: @SJ-B Your question is unclear. Do you want to replace the left side or the unescaped quotes as thg435 assumed?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you want to replace single quotes unless they are inside double quotes.

```
s = " 'replace' : \" \'keep\' \" 'replace' \" '' keep '' \" ..."
> " 'replace' : " 'keep' " 'replace' " '' keep '' " ..."

s.replace(/'(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/g, '"')
> " "replace" : " 'keep' " "replace" " '' keep '' " ..."
```

[more about this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6464500/989121)