# Using POSIX regex in php to remove comments from C source code

Tags: php, regex

I have a problem with removing single line comments from C source code using php and regex.

`/* */` comments are removed so all that is left are `//` comments.

**First**:

I have this regex: `$content = ereg_replace('^\/\/.*$', '', $content);`

This will remove whole file (not only all lines that have `^//comment$`). I assume because its greedy search, but how can I make it non-greedy? And how can I make it do it for all lines that match?

**Second**:

Problem is that they shouldn't be removed while in string `"//shall not be removed"`. How can I make this happen? I was thinking like when it finds `"` char then it should skip it but I have no idea how to do it.

Thanks to all who helps, I really appriciate it.

Comment: This is harder than you think to do correctly. Imagine lines like this: `char * foo = "//don't remove"  " // really please don't"; // But remove this ha ha! // along with this!` and then imagine a copy of that entire line *commented out* on the next line of source. I'd question the entire task and see if there isn't a C source manipulation library you should be using instead.

Comment: Is it? So when I have the choise between doing this by regex or final state machine, u recommend the FSM, right? :/

Comment: It gets worse. `char *bad_regex_strategy = "\"good luck\" // \"counting the \"quotes\"" "//\"//"; // \"ha""" \" " \" ha ha\" ha /// "\;"ha'`

Comment: @BaseZen: There is no need to "[count] the quotes", when you try to do that, the strategy consists to match quoted (or heredoc) parts first in the pattern.

Comment: OK, I meant 'matching', and the complexity argument stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the string trap, a way consists to match what you want to avoid first and to capture it or to skip it.

`ereg_` functions are deprecated since PHP 5.3, however it's always possible to use them:

```
$result = ereg_replace('("([^\\\"]|\\\.)*")|//[^' . "\n" . ']*|/\*\**([^*]|\*\**[^*/])*\*\**/', '\1', $str);
```

It works but the performances are very poor if you compare with the preg version *(that has a lot of features to improve the pattern)*:

```
$pattern2 = '~
    " [^"\\\]* (?s: \\\. [^"\\\]* )*+ " # double quoted string
    (*SKIP)(*F) # forces the pattern to fail and skips the previous substring
  |
    /
    (?:
        / .* # singleline comment 
      |
        \*   # multiline comment 
        [^*]* (?: \*+(?!/) [^*]* )*+  
        (?: \*/ )? # optional to deal with unclosed comments
    )
~xS';

$result = preg_replace($pattern2, '', $str);
```

[online demo](https://regex101.com/r/gQ9nB1/1)

The preg version is about 450x faster than the ereg_ version.

**details of the subpattern** `[^*]* (?: \*+(?!/) [^*]* )*+`:

This subpattern describes the content of a multiline comment, so all between `/*` and the first `*/`:

```
[^*]*           # all that is not an asterisk (can be empty)

(?:             # open a non capturing group:
                # The reason of this group is to handle asterisks that
                # are not a part of the closing sequence */

    \*+         # one or more asterisks 
    (?!/)       # negative lookahead : not followed by / 
                # (it is a zero-width assertion, in other words it's only a test 
                # and it doesn't consume characters)

    [^*]*       # zero or more characters that are not an asterisk
)*+             # repeat the group zero or more times (possessive)
```

Regex engine walk (about) for the string `/*aaaa**bbb***cc***/`:

> **`/*`**`aaaa**bbb***cc***/`         **`/\*`**`[^*]* (?: \*+(?!/) [^*]* )*+ \*/`     *succeed*
>   `/*`**`aaaa`**`**bbb***cc***/`      `/\*`**`[^*]*`**`(?: \*+(?!/) [^*]* )*+ \*/`     *succeed*
>   `/*aaaa**bbb***cc***/`          `/\* [^*]*`**`(?: \*+(?!/) [^*]* )*+`**`\*/`     *try group*
>   `/*aaaa`**`**`**`bbb***cc***/`      `/\* [^*]* (?:`**`\*+`**`(?!/) [^*]* )*+ \*/`   *succeed*
>   `/*aaaa**`**`b`**`bb***cc***/`      `/\* [^*]* (?: \*+`**`(?!/)`**`[^*]* )*+ \*/`   *verified*
>   `/*aaaa**`**`bbb`**`***cc***/`      `/\* [^*]* (?: \*+(?!/)`**`[^*]*`**`)*+ \*/`     *succeed*
>   `/*aaaa**bbb***cc***/`          `/\* [^*]*`**`(?: \*+(?!/) [^*]* )*+`**`\*/`     *try group*
>   `/*aaaa**bbb`**`***`**`cc***/`      `/\* [^*]* (?:`**`\*+`**`(?!/) [^*]* )*+ \*/`   *succeed*
>   `/*aaaa**bbb***`**`c`**`c***/`      `/\* [^*]* (?: \*+`**`(?!/)`**`[^*]* )*+ \*/`   *verified*
>   `/*aaaa**bbb***`**`cc`**`***/`      `/\* [^*]* (?: \*+(?!/)`**`[^*]*`**`)*+ \*/`     *succeed*
>   `/*aaaa**bbb***cc***/`          `/\* [^*]*`**`(?: \*+(?!/) [^*]* )*+`**`\*/`     *try group*
>   `/*aaaa**bbb***cc`**`***`**`/`      `/\* [^*]* (?:`**`\*+`**`(?!/) [^*]* )*+ \*/`   *succeed*
>   `/*aaaa**bbb***cc***`**`/`**        `/\* [^*]* (?: \*+`**`(?!/)`**`[^*]* )*+ \*/`   *fail*
>   `/*aaaa**bbb***cc`**`**`**`*/`      `/\* [^*]* (?:`**`\*+`**`(?!/) [^*]* )*+ \*/`   *backtrack*
>   `/*aaaa**bbb***cc**`**`*`**`/`     `/\* [^*]* (?: \*+`**`(?!/)`**`[^*]* )*+ \*/`   *verified*
>   `/*aaaa**bbb***cc***/`          `/\* [^*]* (?: \*+(?!/)`**`[^*]*`**`)*+ \*/`    *succeed*
>   `/*aaaa**bbb***cc***/`          `/\* [^*]*`**`(?: \*+(?!/) [^*]* )*+`**`\*/`     *try group*
>   `/*aaaa**bbb***cc**`**`*`**`/`      `/\* [^*]* (?:`**`\*+`**`(?!/) [^*]* )*+ \*/`   *succeed*
>   `/*aaaa**bbb***cc***`**`/`**        `/\* [^*]* (?: \*+`**`(?!/)`**`[^*]* )*+ \*/`   *fail*
>   `/*aaaa**bbb***cc***/`          `/\* [^*]*`**`(?: \*+(?!/) [^*]* )*+`**`\*/`     *fail*
>   `/*aaaa**bbb***`**`cc**`**`*/`     `/\* [^*]*`**`(?: \*+(?!/) [^*]* )*+`**`\*/`     *backtrack*
>   `/*aaaa**bbb***cc**`**`*/`**       `/\* [^*]* (?: \*+(?!/) [^*]* )*+`**`\*/`**      *succeed*

Comment: Thank you so much! It is working nicely :) I guess its time to learn preg regular expresion. Just one question. Can u please explain me a bit this line:    [^*]* (?: \*+(?!/) [^*]* )*+ ? Its like I dont want stars 0...n times and then I choose between what?

Comment: @user3457394: I will add the detail of this line in my answer.

Comment: Beautiful :) really appriciate it. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This will match all single line comments but those wrapped by double quotation marks `"`. Even those they say in comments!

```
(?=([^"\\]*(\\.|"([^"\\]*\\.)*[^"\\]*"))*[^"]*$)//.*$
```

**[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/rS3uJ4/1)**

** All rights reserved for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6464500/1020526)*