# Test for / character in between all pairs of opening and closing double quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to test if the `/` character is inside double quotes within a JavaScript string. For instance, `"hello/world"` will match, whereas `hello/world/"How are you"` will fail because it's outside of the double quotes. I've been looking around and haven't found an answer to this.

Also, `"hello"world/how"are you"` should fail as the opening and closing double quotes do not encapsulate the `/`, as determined from left to right. To reiterate, I want to match all instances **within/inside/in between** closing and opening double quotes, which is unlike [Alternative to regex: match all instances not inside quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462578/alternative-to-regex-match-all-instances-not-inside-quotes)

Comment: What should the result be for `"hello"world/how"are you"`?

Comment: @Barmar great question. That should pass as the opening and closing double quotes are not encapsulating the `/`, as determined from left to right

Comment: You should clarify that in the question, since several of the answers get it wrong.

Comment: I think there's confusion about "matching", "failing" and "passing". I have edited my question to be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use this:

```
/^(((\"[^"\/]*\")\/?)|([^"\/]*\/?))+$/igm
```

or

```
/^(\"[^"\/]*\"|[^"\/]*\/?)+$/im
```

[[Regex Demo]](https://regex101.com/r/eP1lE8/1)

Comment: You can simplify it to `/^("[^"\/]*"\/?|[^"\/]*\/?)+$/igm`.

Comment: @Gumbo I wax simplifying it and the best I found is now added ;).

Comment: this works the best so far out of all answers

Answer (score -1):

```
str = 'hello/world"how are you"';

q1 = str.indexOf('"');
q2 = str.lastindexof('"');
slsh = str.indexOf("/");
if( slsh > q1 && slsh <q2){

    dosomething;
}
```

Comment: Why would you edit that? It was perfectly fine.

Comment: If you are not agree you can edit it any time again or roll it back ;).

Comment: Im more upset that I got 2 downvotes with no commemts as to why.

Comment: Agree @StillLearningGuy downvotes  are not motivating us to help share answers lemme upvote yours...

Comment: I'd guess the downvotes are because it's not a useful answer. Why? Well, consider the string `"hello"world/how"are you"` - your answer would (incorrectly) indicate that the '/' IS between '"' - much like every other answer except 1

Comment: I also don't down vote this - but I think you need to use your solution in a loop to check next double-quoted blocks ;).

Comment: It was supposed to be a something to get him started, instead of spoon feexing everyone everything.

Answer (score -1):

Without using regex's an algorithm would be something like... Please test yourself!

```
 Startquotehit = false
    insidequote = false
    Gotaslash = false
    Wantedresult = false

    For x to.. String.length
    {
    If x == quote
    {
     Startquotehit = true;
     Insidequote = !insidequote;
     If gotaslash == true && insidequote
         Wantedresult = true;
    }     

    If x == slash
    {
      If startquotehit
         Gotaslash = true;
    }
 }
```

Wantedresult would tell you if the slash was quoted 'inside quotes' to cover your false scenario of "....".../..."..."

Comment: Why downvote? Yes clumsier than rexexes but it should work :)

Answer (score -2):

```
/".*\/.*"/.test(your_string)
```

See JavaScript regular expressions' [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method.

Comment: This will give the wrong answer for `"quoted begin" not/quoted "quoted end"`

Comment: @Barmar: That's not the example.

Comment: Yes, I generalized. And I guessed correctly that this should pass, see his comment.

Comment: @Barmar: Good that you have clarified the requirements :)

Comment: @Jaromanda X: What's your point? A programming task is not about ANY possible input / output, but a concrete one (unless you are emulating Microsoft).