# Split a special string into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have this string

```
var string = 'foo , bar , "special1,special2,special3" , "random1,random2" , normal , another item'
```

I want to split this on `,` and keep the things within quotes as is in the array i.e i do not want to split the string within quotes. So the expected output would be

```
var array = ['foo', 'bar', 'special1,special2,special3', 'random1,random2', 'normal', 'another item']
```

Comment: thanks. edited the string

Comment: @Pointy I tried splitting on using `split(',')`. Of course it did not work. I tried for loops to detect quotes. That did not give me results either. Why the downvote?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462578/alternative-to-regex-match-all-instances-not-inside-quotes

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string by the  `,`  separator and then remove the double-quotes from any element of array.

```js
var string = 'foo , bar , "special1,special2,special3" , "random1,random2" , normal , another item';

var array = string.split(' , ').map(function(x) {
  return x.replace(/"/g, "")
});

alert(JSON.stringify(array));
```

Comment: This wont work. It will split the things inside the quotes too.

Comment: Why downvotes? Check the updated answer.

Comment: @void you are late :). Though my vote is up only :D

Comment: @PardeepDhingra yeah but i am correct :)

Comment: I've removed your ES6 piece of code, because the question doesn't specifically ask about ES6, and not every browser supports ES6 yet.