# Is there a regular expression that will ignore words that are surronded by quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression that will not match words in quotes but will match words without quotes e.g

-"Welcome" - false
 -Welcome - true

Comment: I have tried to extract the ones with quotes and removing them with this
"([^"])*(\bwelcome\b)" but thats not a correct soltion

Comment: @DanielBeck quoting OP: "that will **not** match words in quotes".  Emphasis mine.

Comment: What about multiple words?  Should the expression accommodate multiple words in quotes? (e.g. `"this has four" words` would match only the word "words")

Comment: @JosephMarikle at max in the use case it only going to be 2 words

Comment: So what output do you expect for `"two" words`, and for `two words`?

Comment: @trincot "two" words - two would not be matched
for two words - the word two would be matched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match only those words that are followed by an *even* number of double quotes, which means they themselves are not within quotes (assuming your quotes are always paired):

```
\w+(?=[^"]*("[^"]*"[^"]*)*$)
```

```js
function getWord(txt) {
  txt = txt.match(/\w+(?=[^"]*("[^"]*"[^"]*)*$)/);
  return txt && txt[0];
}

var input = document.querySelector('input');
var output = document.querySelector('span');

input.oninput = function () {
  output.textContent = getWord(input.value);
}

input.oninput();
```

```html
Word: <input value='"two" words'><br>
First non-quoted: <span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

`(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)` will exclude all double quotes in the string and all text within those double quotes.
This will also remove all newline characters if you have any
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462578/alternative-to-regex-match-all-instances-not-inside-quotes) is my source