# RegEx for matching different types of quotes

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I write small scripting 'language' for my game.

I would like to allow for every JS string literal strings(`` `"' ``).

I figured out how to check everything inside those using:

```
(?<e1>""|'|`)(?:\$\k<e1>|(?!\k<e1>).)*\k<e1>)
```

It works.
But now, I have a different trouble. I need to remove all tabs, that are not inside those types of quotes.

I looked up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462578/alternative-to-regex-match-all-instances-not-inside-quotes) how to match everything, that is not inside quotes:

```
\t(?=([^"\\]*(\\.|"([^"\\]*\\.)*[^"\\]*"))*[^"]*$)
```

And I got trouble connecting those two worlds so that `` "a`\t`" `` does not remove this middle tab as

```
\t(?=([^"'`$]*(\$.|['`"]([^"'`$]*\$.)*[^"'`$]*["`']))*[^"`']*$)
```

does. I know, I have to check for the last not-escaped (with `$` not `\`) quote, but how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match what you don't want and keep what you want using a capturing group.

In this case you could wrap your first pattern in a capturing group and add an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) using the pipe `|` after it to match 1+ times a tab.

In the replacement use the first capturing group:

```
((?<e1>""|'|`)(?:\$\k<e1>|(?!\k<e1>).)*\k<e1>)|\t+
^                                            ^^^^^
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H2B0Pd/1/)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know how to start thinking about it, but now, when you showed me how I will know for the future. Very clever way! Thank you very much.