# how to split a string with delimiter with unescaped delimiter character

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to split a string with (ex:|) delimter. Here, my problem is string contains with escape characters. How i need to delete the delimiter within esacape character.

The data looks like:

> null|123456|xxx12345|123|-11234|123|2000-01-01|XXX|01|0.000000000000|0.000000000000|0.000000000000|"AAA |AAA Data Group (AAA Inc)"|null|2000-01-01|null|null|xx

```scala
val delimit='|'
val inputData = 'null|123456|xxx12345|123|-11234|123|2000-01-01|XXX|01|0.000000000000|0.000000000000|0.000000000000|"AAA |AAA Data Group (AAA Inc)"|null|-|2000-01-01|-|null|null|xx'
inputData.split(delimit).map(x=>{println(x)})
```

I expected the result:

```
null
123456
xxx12345
123
-11234
123
2000-01-01
XXX
01
0.000000000000
0.000000000000
0.000000000000
"AAA AAA Data Group (AAA Inc)"
null
2000-01-01
null
null
xx
```

but the actual output is:\n

```
null
123456
xxx12345
123
-11234
123
2000-01-01
XXX
01
0.000000000000
0.000000000000
0.000000000000
"AAA 
AAA Data Group (AAA Inc)"
null
2000-01-01
null
null
xx
```

Answer (score 0):

`split` accepts regex, so you could use right regex to split only if `|` is not inside quotes:

```
val inputData = """null|123456|xxx12345|123|-11234|123|2000-01-01|XXX|01|0.000000000000|0.000000000000|0.000000000000|"AAA |AAA Data Group (AAA Inc)"|null|-|2000-01-01|-|null|null|xx"""

inputData.split("\|(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)")

// Array(null, 123456, xxx12345, 123, -11234, 123, 2000-01-01, XXX, 01, 0.000000000000, 0.000000000000, 0.000000000000, "AAA |AAA Data Group (AAA Inc)", null, -, 2000-01-01, -, null, null, xx)
```

I've borrowed regex from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462578/alternative-to-regex-match-all-instances-not-inside-quotes/23667311).