# Regex: split string by character except if inside quotes or double quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, string, quotes, double-quotes

I need to split a string using a delimiter character (**=** in my example) , except if this character is inside quotes or double quotes

I succeed to do it within single quotes using `\=+(?=(?:(?:[^']*'){2})*[^']*$)` , or within double quotes using `\=+(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)`, but not for both, what would be the appropriate RegExp ?

Bonus: if it can also split when the character is not inside character **`** , it would be perfect :)

[image]

[image]

What I need :

[image]

**Edit:** Javascript example to reproduce ( https://jsfiddle.net/cgnorhm0/ )

```
function splitByCharExceptInsideString(str, delimiterChar) {
    // split line by character except when it is inside quotes
    const escapedChar = delimiterChar.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+!<=:?./\\^$|#\s,]/g, "\\$&");
    const regSplit = new RegExp(escapedChar + `+(?=(?:(?:[^']*'){2})*[^']*$)`);
    const splits = str.split(regSplit);
    return splits ;
}

const testStr = `image.inside {
    sshagent(credentials: ['ssh-creds']) {
        env.GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -T -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"
        env.GIT_SSH_COMMAND2='ssh -T -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'
    }
}`;
const delimiterChar = '=';

const splitLs = splitByCharExceptInsideString(testStr,delimiterChar);
console.log(splitLs);
```

Comment: Why not try an alternative method to split the string.

Comment: If you have one i'm all ears :)

Comment: can you please post your test string as code?

Comment: This is a pretty difficult question with no easy answer. [See more discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462578/regex-to-match-all-instances-not-inside-quotes)

Comment: I added  the test string as code

Comment: Both regex do not handle this example: `'inside = ' and another = '...`

Comment: Why do you need to do this anyways? Seems illogical. Use logic instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lookahead and lookbehind don't consume character so you can use multiple of them together. you can use

```
\=+(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)(?=(?:(?:[^']*'){2})*[^']*$)(?=(?:(?:[^`]*`){2})*[^`]*$)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RBMTk9/2)

Comment: This will fail when the quotes do not match like this: `'inside = ' and another = '...`

Answer (score 0):

The regex below finds `=` characters that are not inside `, ", or ' pairs.

```js
const regex = /=(?=.*)(?=(?:'.*?'|".*?"|`.*?`).*?)/;
```

[Behavior with your example](https://regex101.com/r/w3KlZA/1):
[image]

Comment: not working :/ https://imgur.com/a/MLNGfwc

Comment: very odd, I'm using the same website and it's working for me...

Comment: Are you using the javascript syntax?

Comment: can you save on regex101 and post the link ?