# Substitude everything in "()" but ignore those cases where round brackects are inside square brackets "<>" in regrex

Tags: python, regex

Hi I am trying to use regrex to replace everything surounded by "()" with an empty string "", but not in the case where "()" is in an angle bracket. e.g. "<..()>" should be ignored and not replaced.
Example input:

```
Hi<Hi(now)>_(.)
```

Example output:

```
Hi<Hi(now)>_
```

Following what I read from [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462578/regex-to-match-all-instances-not-inside-quotes)

I have tried using the following method:

```
example = "Hi<Hi(now)>_(.)"
regex = re.compile(r"\<[^\>]*\>|(\([^\)]*\))")
re.sub(regex, '', str(first_p))
```

But it instead outputted

```
'Hi_'
```

Can anyone explain what might have gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrapped the wrong alternative with a capturing group and missed the backreference in the replacement part:

```py
import re
example = "Hi<Hi(now)>_(.)"
regex = re.compile(r"(<[^<>]*>)|\([^()]*\)")
print( re.sub(regex, r'\1', example) )
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/CUpNtm).

Note the `<` and `>` are not special chars, and need not escaping.

The `(<[^<>]*>)|\([^()]*\)` pattern *captures* into Group 1 any substring that starts with `<`, then has zero or more chars other than `<` and `>` and then ends with `>`, and just matches any substring between `(` and `)` having no other `(` and `)` in between.

The `\1` replacement puts back the captured substring where it was.