# Regex to split parameters

Tags: java, regex, string

I am looking for a regular expression to split a string on commas. Sounds very simple, but there is another restriction. The parameters on the string could have commas surrounded by parenthesis which should not split the string.

*Example:*

```
1, 2, 3, add(4, 5, 6), 7, 8
 ^  ^  ^      !  !   ^  ^
```

The string should only be splitted by the commas marked with ^ and not with !.

I found a solution for it here: [A regex to match a comma that isn't surrounded by quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700953/a-regex-to-match-a-comma-that-isnt-surrounded-by-quotes)

*Regex:*

```
,(?=([^\(]*\([^\)]*\))*[^\)]*$)
```

**But my string could be more complex:**

```
1, 2, 3, add(4, 5, add(6, 7, 8), 9), 10, 11
 ^  ^  ^      !  !      !  !   !   ^   ^
```

For this string the result is wrong and i have no clue how to fix this or if it even is possible with regular expressions.

Have anyone an idea how to resolve this problem?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: By all means try to avoid using `,(?=([^\(]*\([^\)]*\))*[^\)]*$)`, it is a means of last resort.

Comment: are the escape only the parenthesis or do you use the keyword add(...)?

Comment: @LoicM. "add" is just an example here and could be anything else. The main point is that commas in parenthesis should NOT split the string!

Comment: You will have to write a parser

Comment: Agree with @TheLostMind. A regex solution will be too complex to be something you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also achieve this using this regex: `([^,(]+(?=,|$)|[\w]+\(.*\)(?=,|$))`

[regex online demo](https://regex101.com/r/cmDV9n/2)

Considering this text `1, 2, 3, add(4, 5, add(6, 7, 8), 9), 10, 11` it creates groups based on commas (not surrounded by `()`)

So, the output would be:

```
Match 1
Group 1.    0-1    `1`

Match 2
Group 1.    2-4    ` 2`

Match 3
Group 1.    5-7    ` 3`

Match 4
Group 1.    9-35    `add(4, 5, add(6, 7, 8), 9)`

Match 5
Group 1.    36-39    ` 10`

Match 6
Group 1.    40-43    ` 11`
```

Comment: I asked for a regEx solution and your answer looks pretty good at my tests. So i vote yours as the correct answer. But my tests show also that the java method i posted as an answer is a little bit faster than this. Therefore i will use the java method to parse the string.

Comment: black magic..  I was trying to achieve this with a recursive pattern when I threw in the towel and found this.  Bravo

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I think a regular expression is not very useful for this. A small block of java might be easier.

So this is my java code for solving the problem:

```
public static void splitWithJava() {
    String EXAMPLE = "1, 2, 3, add(4, 5, add(7, 8), 6), 7, 8";
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int start = 0;
    int pCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < EXAMPLE.length(); i++) {
      char c = EXAMPLE.charAt(i);
      switch (c) {
      case ',': {
        if (0 == pCount) {
          list.add(EXAMPLE.substring(start, i).trim());
          start = i + 1;
        };
        break;
      }
      case '(': {
        pCount++;
        break;
      }
      case ')': {
        pCount--;
        break;
      }
      }
    }
    list.add(EXAMPLE.substring(start).trim());
    for (String str : list) {
      System.out.println(str);
    }
  }
```