# Why does this split create duplicates?

Tags: javascript

I have the following line which splits correctly but produces a duplicate for "abc"

```js
console.log("squadName, \"abc\"".split(/,\s*(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/))
```

The expected output should be the same as that of

```js
console.log("squadName, \"abc\"".split(/,\s*/))
```

However, I'm trying to ignore commas within quotes, as explained in [A regex to match a comma that isn't surrounded by quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700953/a-regex-to-match-a-comma-that-isnt-surrounded-by-quotes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parentheses in a JS regular expression explicitly create a capture group. If you prepend the contents with `?:`, it will instead be a non-capturing group. If you see `(?` in general this is usually a special kind of paren-grouping value.

For your code, you'd want to do:

```js
console.log("squadName, \"abc\"".split(/,\s*(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/))
```